# Properties of a supremum of a parametrized set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Please I need help solving this question:

$E(x)= \left \{ \left(1+ \frac{x}{n} \right)^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$.
Let $a(x) = \sup E(x)$ (least upper bound).

(1)Prove that $a(x) < a(y)$ if $0 < x < y$.

(2) Prove that $a(x)a(y) \leq \left( a \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right) \right) ^ 2$.

I already proved that E(x) has no largest element and is bounded and I proved part 1.

But I'm having trouble with the proof in part 2. Any help please?

Comment: What is the supremum of $E(x)$? May it be $e^x$?

Comment: yes, it is e^x!

Comment: Then, $a(x)a(y)=e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$. On the other hand, $a((x+y)/2)^2=(e^{(x+y)/2})^2=e^{x+y}$.

Comment: the "a" is also included in the parenthese:  $\left( a \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right) \right) ^ 2$

Comment: also how can we prove that it is less than or equal? not just only equal?

Comment: Yes yes. It was a mistake. Well... If it is equal, then it is less than or equal to. I don't think there are $x,y$ for which the inequality is strict. They should be equal.

Comment: okay, thank you

Comment: Your welcome :)

Comment: Show that for a given $x\in\mathbb {R} $ the sequence $(1+x/n)^n$ is increasing and hence the supremum $a(x) $ of $E(x) $ is same as limit of this sequence ie $$a(x) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$ and then prove the desired properties using limits.